# Isometric scene - how?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I programmed a simple 2d app/ game.I just noticed, that an isometric scene instead of the 2d one would look gorgeous . I did not use any SpriteKit, etc. , it's just a simple single-view-app.

Now I draw some nice isometric vectors of e.g. a petrol station, which I would love to use instead of the plain 2D-images. For sure I can just use them as an imageview. But my idea was that I may animate driving cars in straight ways, so that they seem to be 3D (isometric), but are just images moving along a given path. What is the best way to do this? Can I use my isometric image as a Gamescene (never used)?

Greetings!

Comment: Were you thinking of something like this? https://dribbble.com/shots/6362521-Fuel-Station-at-Night

Comment: You have a pretty generic question to leave a specific answer, but I would suggest looking into SKTileMapNode.  It supports isometric tile maps

Answer (score -1):

If you’ve been doing without SpriteKit so far, I don’t see any need to use it now. Keep them as UIImageViews, and animate their positions normally, just make sure that the point you move them to makes sense, so as not to break the illusion.

You can open up your image in Preview, click and drag along it’s direction to make a rectangular selection along that direction, and use the width and height of that box to make a ratio, like 20:25, which then simplifies to 4:5. Meaning for every 4 points it moves along x-axis, it should move 5 points along y-axis. Then store this ratio as a CGPoint somewhere in your code, note that all your isometric images should give you this same ratio.

Then you could make an abstraction that moves an imageview x points along its direction, using that ratio. Say you want to move it 100 points along its direction, and say the ratio is 4:5. The ratio is a triangle of width 4, height 5. You use **a**^2=**b**^2+**c**^2 to calculate the hypotenuse of that triangle. Then find a **k** such that **ck**=100. Then multiply **a** and **b** by that **k** to give you your delta x and delta y. Apply those deltas to its current position and you have the final position to animate to, which will be 100 points along its direction.